# How to push file from PC to android phone programatically?

Tags: android, adb

I want to use **adb push** command in my activity so i can transfer file from windows PC to phone. is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible from the Android side as "adb.exe" is a windows application in the platform-tools directory.  If you write a Windows application, it can issue the "adb push" command.

Comment: can you suggest me how can i push file from windows to android programmaticaly ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want.  If you want to "push" files from Windows, then it will be coming from a windows app onto the Android phone?  If you want to "pull" files from the Windows side onto the Android phone, you could use something like an FTP or Web server on your windows box and connect to that in Android.  I don't think you can do anything with adb.exe itself from the Android side.

Comment: @ brianestey yes i got the point i have wrote a java program which can push file to emulator, now i dont know how to push in android phone as "adb push " will push in emulator not in phone.

Comment: Why not?  I can issue the command 'adb push "C:\1.jpg" "/mnt/sdcard/1.jpg" via command line.  That should work through a java app that runs a similar command.  What errors do you see?

Comment: Also, in case you weren't aware, the DDMS perspective in Eclipse allows you to push files through the "File Explorer" tab as well.

Comment: hey i got the answer just write "adb push source mnt/sdcard" e.g. "adb push C:\temp.txt mnt/sdcard"

Comment: @SchoolBoy can you help me to do the same, i want to pull file to windows from android device ? using command i can do like `adb pull /sdcard/juned.jpg /root/juned/android_usb/` how to do it programmatically [please check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615532/send-file-to-computer-system-using-usb) ?