# how to push file from PC to sdcard in android mobile using abd push command?

Tags: android, adb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to push file from PC to andriod phone programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060750/how-to-push-file-from-pc-to-andriod-phone-programatically)

I want to push file from PC to android mobile using abd push command i know for the emulator but how to fo that for phone?

Comment: You just asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8060750/591801

Comment: @paresh Mayani can you explain me how to do that?

Comment: @AmolBhanushali: Paresh means that you have to wait for answers to your questions, then vote on them (up if they are useful, down if they are not useful), then select as THE answer the one that answers your question.

Comment: thank you tzot and paresh for guiding me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As according to me..through command line,First enter inside android-sdk/tools and then use the command as:

adb -s (your phone recognising number) shell
[you can get your phone recognising number as adb devices(attach ur device as well)]then,

adb push (your filename) /sdcard/(filename)

Thanks..

Comment: Does not work any more with Android 4.3. Verified with S4 Google Play edition.